# Need help in RPG maker XP. Text to speech

Tags: accessibility, game-engine, color-blindness, rpgmakermv

I am helping someone making a game in RPG maker XP for blind. Which means they can't read the text on screen. Now someone in the game community told me that text to speech could be implemented, but I have no idea how to do it. I am also blind, so I do not have access to RPG maker XP for script making.
We want to use this library here: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/tree/master/extras/controllerClient
Would anyone be able to look into this and try to make a script that could work with this? This would be so nice.
Thank you all for reading.

The game in question is Pokémon Reborn. Text to speech would let blind people play by reading out text on screen, so that we could here it.

Comment: This is a worthy cause, but Stack Overflow is not a site for this kind of volunteer work so your question might be closed.  If you read the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" link it explains that this site is for getting help with focused, specific questions.  If you have a question about some code you've written that uses the library you linked then we can help.  See: how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   and what types of questions NOT to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: If there is a forum for  RPG maker XP  you might want to ask this question there.  Also, if the  RPG maker XP developers take suggestions you could ask them to build text-to-speech into the engine.